# alt-tab to desktop in XFCE

Tags: linux, desktop, alt-tab, xfce4

I use Linux with the XFCE 4 environment.

When I'm playing a game, sometimes I want to go on Internet, for example to get some info about something I don't understand.
As the game is fullscreen I might just use Alt-Tab to get to the desktop, open my web browser, and continue.
However XFCE's Alt-Tab doesn't include the desktop, and if I don't have a app opened, I'm stuck, and I have to either quit the game then restart it, or go into the settings of the game disable fullscreen then change it again. This is painful.

Is there an alt-tab tool that allows to go to the desktop directly, compatible with XFCE 4 ?

Comment: I found a workaround, setting a keyboard shortcut to open a terminal, to get to the desktop. But it's still a little bit painful, especially when I close the terminal before the web browser opens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the default window manager for xfce then you can switch workspaces with

`ctrl + alt + LEFT/RIGHT`

If you don't have another workspace, then the default key binding to make a new workspace is

`Alt + Insert`

To remove a workspace

`Alt + Delete`

I hope this helps ;)